# What is Ei in paper "How to Combine a Billion Alphas" by Zura Kakushadze?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio-management, portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-selection

I am reading paper  ["How to Combine a Billion Alphas"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05937) by Zura Kakushadze.
In the paper, it has Ei which are the expected returns for alphas.
It also has Ri hat as follows. I wonder what the difference is between Ei and Ri hat?
[image]

Comment: Isn't $R_{i,s}$ just the realised return of your alpha, e.g. momentum, and $E_{i,t}$ would be the expected return $\mathbb E[R_{i,s}]$?

Comment: Yes， I agree with you. But in the paper, it also has Ri hat, which seems also equal expected return E[Ri,s]. I wonder the difference between Ei and Ri hat.